# python-docx installation on windows

Tags: python, libxml2, python-docx, libxslt

When I try to install python-docx on my machine, I get errors that I haven't seen in other questions... here's the command prompt code-

```
C:\windows\system32>pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Using cached python-docx-0.8.5.tar.gz
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2 (from python-docx)
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml, python-docx
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\python.exe"
 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\pip-build-zk13t9st\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open
', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --r
ecord C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-auod13yy-record\install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
Building lxml version 3.6.0.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
*

Using build configuration of libxslt
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\html
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isosc
hematron
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml
copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includ
es
copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include
s
copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include
s
copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes

copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\includes
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\include
s
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib
.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win
32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win
32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron
-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstra
ct_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-        schema
tron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_i
nclude.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-    schematro
n-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema
tron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win32-    3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-sch
ematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema
tron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-  3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\
xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_f
or_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-   schemat
ron-xslt1
copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt
 -> build\lib.win32-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptool
s, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-  zk13t9
st\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) (__file__).read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record    C:\Users\usr\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip-auod13yy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in    C:\Users\usr\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\pip-build-zk13t9st\lxml\
```

*covered my username with 'usr'. 
What's the error with 'xslt-config' not being recognized? I've searched that too but nothing I tried worked. I also tried to install libxml2 and libxslt, but that didn't work either (not recognized on the pypi?). The error about not finding the 'vcvarsall.bat' is confusing as well. Then it goes on at the end to say "compile failed with error code 1". Does anyone know what the computer is trying to tell me? I've tried reading through this code multiple times and haven't been able to reach a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxml2 and libxslt are C-code libraries that lxml depends on. You might try installing lxml from a binary distribution and see if that gets you past this.

Comment: You saved me! But how you understand that this will solve the problem?

Comment: The `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` means `pip` is trying to compile part of the package. This may work ok if you have a C compiler installed, but on Windows that's typically not the case. Wanting to compile indicates it can't find a binary dependency and is trying to create it itself. On Windows the solution is often to install the binary instead.